# Mock JWT AuthenticationPrincipal while testing REST end points

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

We are building REST API and adding AuthenticationPrincipal as method argument

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> listProduct(
    @Valid @RequestParam(value = "fields", required = false) final String fields,
    @Valid @RequestParam(value = "offset", required = false) final Integer offset,
    @Valid @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false) final Integer limit,
    @AuthenticationPrincipal final Jwt jwt) throws Exception {

    //Extract roles from jwt and do advanced role checking. 
}
```

While testing using mockmvc

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
} 

@Test
void testGetListProductsWithFields() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
    attributeMap.put(null, "");

    //Code

    final var result = mvc
    .perform(get("/api" + requestFields)
        .with(jwt().authorities(new OAuth2UserAuthority("ROLE_my_roll", attributeMap)))
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andReturn();
}
```

JWT token is getting initialised using constructor (`org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt`) at `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` and since no token is being sent assertion errors are thrown. Idea is not to connect to auth provider to generate tokens

Call trace

```
Jwt(AbstractOAuth2Token).<init>(String, Instant, Instant) line: 55  
Jwt.<init>(String, Instant, Instant, Map<String,Object>, Map<String,Object>) line: 69   
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor<?>, Object[]) line: not available [native method]    
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 62    
DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 45    
Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: 490 
BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Constructor<T>, Object...) line: 204 
ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor).constructAttribute(Constructor<?>, String, MethodParameter, WebDataBinderFactory, NativeWebRequest) line: 320   
ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor).createAttribute(String, MethodParameter, WebDataBinderFactory, NativeWebRequest) line: 224  
ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(String, MethodParameter, WebDataBinderFactory, NativeWebRequest) line: 85  
ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor).resolveArgument(MethodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory) line: 139   
HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(MethodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory) line: 121    
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).getMethodArgumentValues(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 167 
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).invokeForRequest(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 134    
ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 105    
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 878  
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 792   
RequestMappingHandlerAdapter(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter).handle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Object) line: 87 
TestDispatcherServlet(DispatcherServlet).doDispatch(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1040 
TestDispatcherServlet(DispatcherServlet).doService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 943   
TestDispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1006  
TestDispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 898    
TestDispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 626   
TestDispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 883  
TestDispatcherServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 72 
TestDispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 733   
MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 167 
MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 320 
FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterInvocation) line: 126    
FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 90   
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 118 
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 137    
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 111  
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 158    
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 63 
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 114    
BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119  
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
LogoutFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 116   
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
CsrfFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 103   
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 92    
HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 77  
HeaderWriterFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119   
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 105   
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 56    
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119 
FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 334 
FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 215   
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 178   
SecurityMockMvcConfigurer$DelegateFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 132   
MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
MockMvc.perform(RequestBuilder) line: 183
```

Tried to pass jwt constructor parameters as request parameter.

```
Map<String, Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<>();
attributeMap.put(null, "");

//Code

final Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
headerMap.put("alg", "none");

final var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final var jsonMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(headerMap);

final var result = mvc
.perform(get("/api" + requestFields)
        .with(jwt().authorities(new OAuth2UserAuthority("ROLE_my_roll", attributeMap)))
        .param("tokenValue", "tokenValue")
        .param("!headers", jsonMap)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andReturn();
```

But it throws different error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Tried adding converter. But no luck

```
@Component
public class StringToMapConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convert(final String source) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(source,
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getInputType(final TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructFromCanonical(String.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getOutputType(final TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructFromCanonical(Map.class.getName());
    }
}
```

I am able to solve this by extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and proving `argumentResolver`

```
//Test configuration

@ContextConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@TestConfiguration
public class ProductApiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addArgumentResolvers(
            final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(getArgumentResolver());
    }

    private HandlerMethodArgumentResolver getArgumentResolver() {
        return new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
            @Override
            public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
                return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(Jwt.class);
            }

            @Override
            public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter parameter,
                    final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                    final NativeWebRequest webRequest, final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory)
                    throws Exception {

                final var roles = new JSONArray();
                roles.add("my_role");

                final Map<String, JSONArray> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
                jsonMap.put("roles", roles);

                final var claimObject = new JSONObject(jsonMap);
                final var jwt = Jwt.withTokenValue("token")
                        .header("alg", "none")
                        .claim("realm_access", claimObject)
                        .build();
                final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_my_roll");
                final var token = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
                return token.getToken();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since this is not per test i can't change the jwt token for each test and verify different scenarios.

Is there a simple way to mock the method argument in the controller class when an API is being tested by webmvc?

Answer (score 3):

We were able to solve this issue by setting SecurityContextHolder

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@MockBean
SecurityContext securityContext;

@Test
public void test() {

    //some code

    given(securityContext.getAuthentication())
        .willReturn(Utils
            .getMockJwtToken("my_role", "testSubject"));
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

    final var result = this.mvc
        .perform(get("/api" + requestFields)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
}
```

And Test util class

```
public class Utils {

    private Utils() {
    
    }

    public static JwtAuthenticationToken getMockJwtToken(String role, String subject){
        final var roles = new JSONArray();
        roles.add(role);

        final Map<String, JSONArray> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonMap.put("roles", roles);

        final var claimObject = new JSONObject(jsonMap);
        final var jwt = Jwt.withTokenValue("token")
                .header("alg", "none")
                .claim("realm_access", claimObject)
                .subject(subject)
                .build();
        final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_my_role));
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
    }
}
```